# How can I get help on terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, manpage, documentation, info

I often see things like

> read `man xyz`
>   For more information read *xyz'*s man page.
>   see `info xyz`

so I wonder:

- How can I get help on terminal commands generally?
- What exactly are these *man* and *info pages*?
- How can I find and view them?

Comment: Partially a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/468629/how-do-i-view-the-man-pages

Comment: [Chat room for the question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71150/discussion-about-https-askubuntu-com-q-991946-507051)

Comment: I'd also like to mention [tldr.sh](https://tldr.sh), which is an effort to simplify and present man pages in a better way.

Comment: @Nodon'tshownmyrealname Would you write an answer about [`tldr`](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr)? You could also mention [`cheat`](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat) and maybe [cheat.sh](https://github.com/chubin/cheat.sh).

Comment: Related: [Any command/tool to show example of a command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816056/any-command-tool-to-show-example-of-a-command)

Comment: Particularly related topic: [Where can I find the location of folders for installed programs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54395/566421)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## What is a *man page*?

A man page (short for manual page) is the traditional form of software documentation on a Unix-like OS like Ubuntu. For the vast majority of commands and programs there's a man page which lists its options and explains its usage.

## How can I find and view man pages?

### Offline in a terminal

Man pages are automatically installed on your system together with the commands they describe. To view and search man pages there's the command `man`:

```
man mv
```

displays the man page of `mv` while

```
man -k mv
```

searches names and short descriptions of all installed man pages for the string `mv`. POSIX Extended Regular Expressions are allowed and it's a *search*, so this will also find e.g. `git-mv` and `semver`, if you want to search exactly `mv` use `^mv$` instead.

See [What is the difference between `man` and `man (#)`?](https://askubuntu.com/q/365548/507051) to read about man page sections. For more information read `man`'s man page. ;)

#### How can I influence how a man page is displayed?

The default program to display man pages is `less`. This so-called **pager** provides a helpful search function, just enter `/` followed by the search term, e.g.

```
/--version
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will mark every finding and scroll to the first one. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to go to the next finding and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to go to the previous one (see [How can I search within a manpage?](https://askubuntu.com/q/20752/507051)). For a list of commands press <kbd>H</kbd>, to exit `less` press <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Beside `less` there are **other pagers** available: `pg`, `most` and `w3m` just to list three. I recommend `most`: It comes with a very useful coloring of key words making a man page *much* easier to read and navigate, see for yourself:

[image: most screenshot displaying mv's manpage]

To view a man page in a different than your default pager use the `-P` option, e.g.:

```
man -P most mv
```

If you want to **change the default pager** manpages are displayed with you have two options:

- change the default pager solely of `man`

  ```
  export MANPAGER=most
  ```

  To make the change persistent add this command to your `~/.bashrc` file.
- change the default pager of your whole system

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config pager
  ```

<sub>Fans can even (ab)use `vim` as the `MANPAGER`, see [this article](https://murukesh.me/2015/08/28/vim-for-man.html) written by [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru).</sub>

Man pages are displayed in the **font** specified in your terminal emulator settings. If you work with the terminal regularly you might want to change this font; I can only recommend [Hack – a typeface designed for source code](http://sourcefoundry.org/hack/), see the screenshot above for its beauty.

### Offline via GUI

A nice and easy way to display man pages with a **simple GUI** is the preinstalled `yelp` program. To start a man page with `yelp` execute `yelp man:PROGRAM` or `gnome-help man:PROGRAM`, e.g.:

```
yelp man:mv
```

You can also view man pages with your preferred **browser**, see [How do I make man pages open in a web browser?](https://askubuntu.com/q/339255/507051), e.g. for `man mv` in `firefox`:

```
man -Hfirefox mv
```

Last but not least you can **convert** man pages **to PDF** and view them with your preferred PDF viewer, see: [Is there a way to print info/man pages to PDF?](https://askubuntu.com/q/962558/507051)

### Online

#### http://manpages.ubuntu.com

You can view the man pages of programs available via the repositories of every currently supported Ubuntu version with the shorthand URL `manpg.es/PROGRAM`, e.g. http://manpg.es/mv. This opens `mv`'s man page for the *latest* Ubuntu release, you can choose a different release in the top bar. To search for man pages you can use e.g. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=mv.

As explained above `man` can only display man pages of software installed on the system. To view man pages from http://manpages.ubuntu.com using a terminal pager there's `dman` available in the `bikeshed` package.

#### Other sources

When you read documentation from other online sources it's a good idea to keep an eye on the program version. Most programs have a `--version` option that displays the version of the program in question, e.g.

```
$ mv --version
mv (GNU coreutils) 8.25
```

There are a lot of websites which dedicated themselves to make man pages easily available, I'm just going to present the two I like the most:

- [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) comes with useful syntax highlighting, but it features only the last released version of the program
- [manpag.es](http://manpag.es/ubuntu1604/1+mv) hosts man pages of Ubuntu releases long gone EOL

---

<sup>Source not already linked: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/man/</sup>

Comment: Another helpful trick (at least if you're a programmer) is to write a small script to dump man's output into your text editor of choice.  E.g. (\n is newline)  #!/bin/tcsh\n
set name = $argv[$#argv]\n
set file = /tmp/man.$name.out\n
/usr/bin/man $* | col -bx > $file\n
(path to your editor) $file\n
rm $file\n  A similar but editor-specific macro will allow you to call man from within the editor, which is quite helpful.

Comment: @jamesqf Interesting, why do you do and when do you use that? As editors are usually able to read from stdin you can simplify it to e.g. `man $*|col -bx|nano -` or `man $*|col -bx|kate -i`.

Comment: @jamesqf if you export man page to text file in order to search or navigate easily, you really should consider having a look at the _"SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS"_ page.It can be opened by typing 'h' in `less` (`man` use `less` command for pagination so it works from `man` too)

Comment: @Ludovic Ronsin: I do it in my editor rather than less for two reasons.  First, because I know my editor's commands (which are far more powerful than the less commands), and don't have to bother learning yet another set of commands, which I would inevitably confuse in different contexts.  Second, because I can hook the editor version to a keypress (Alt-m, as it happens) and thereby get help on any function call that has a man page.  As for why I do it the way I do, I wrote it 20+ years ago, and it worked well enough.

Comment: @jamesqf would just setting PAGER="vim -" do?

Comment: @d33tah: Might if I used vim regularly.  Might even work with my editor, from the command line.  But my main motivation was to be able to access man from within an editor session.  As usual with *nix, there are many ways to achieve a goal acceptably well.  What's important is knowing that something is possible, e.g. that you aren't limited to the system default man output.

Answer (score 15):

The basics have been covered already, but one website I think is quite helpful for telling you what a command does is https://explainshell.com, which breaks down a command into its sections and shows what each bit does.

[image]

Comment: +1 That's absolutely *not* what I was after when I wrote this Q&A, but it's a great resource I didn't know about  – thank you very much! As the other answers deliberately cover one main topic, maybe you extend your answer to cover online tools in general? https://www.shellcheck.net comes to mind…

Answer (score 13):

## What is an *info page*?

Alongside

```
man program-name
```

there is often also

```
info program-name
```

Sometimes they are the same (duplicates), but sometimes one of these pages contains more information. For example

```
info ddrescue
```

contains more information than

```
man ddrescue
```

and

```
info date
```

contains more information than

```
man date
```

The balance between `man` and `info` depends on the policy of the people who maintain the particular program [package].

See this link for more details,

[unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/difference-between-help-info-and-man-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/difference-between-help-info-and-man-command)

Answer (score 13):

## What is the `help` command?

`help` displays helpful information about `bash` built-in commands. It provides help for bash shell commands only. You can use `type` to determine whether a command is such a built-in, e.g. `type echo` vs. `type rm`.

It is called with a pattern as an argument:

```
help if
```

displays the help page for the `if` command. If you're just interested in the syntax of a command use the `-s` option, if you want `help` to produce output in `man` page format use `-m`. To view long help texts conveniently you can pipe the output to your preferred pager (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/991947/507051)'s “How can I influence” section):

```
help -m if | less
```

#### Comparison with `man` and `info`

You can run and compare the following commands:

```bsh
help echo  # for the bash built-in command `echo`
man echo   # for the program `/bin/echo`
info echo  # for the program `/bin/echo`
```

Like in this example there are programs who are available *both* as a built-in and a usual program (see [Why is there a /bin/echo and why would I want to use it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960822/507051)), in this case the man page usually contains a note indicating that.

See this link for more details: [Difference between help, info and man command · U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/difference-between-help-info-and-man-command)

## a program's option `-h` and/or `--help`

Usually there is built-in help in the programs themselves available via at least one of the options `-h`, `--help` or `-?`:

```
PROGRAM -h
PROGRAM --help
PROGRAM -?
```

If both options `-h` and `--help` exist, they are often equivalent, but sometimes you get 'more help' with `--help`, `-H`, `--longhelp`, `--help-all` or similar commands. This behaviour is documented in the program's `man`/`info` page.

Usually there is more information via `man` and `info`, but sometimes there is exclusive information via `-h`. Run and compare the output of

```
man lsblk
```

and

```
lsblk -h
```

Some programs like `df`, `tar` and `rsync` use the option `-h` for something else. This is described in the `man`/`info` page of each program.

Again you can pipe the output to your preferred pager, e.g.:

```
lsblk -h | less
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `--help`, that is often the only thing I need with most commands, and always the first thing I try.

Answer (score 7):

## What is a tutorial and how can I find a useful one

When you have some experience of linux, the **man** pages, **info** pages and **help** options are very useful. But in the beginning, they can be difficult to understand; you need more detailed help to get started.

You can find detailed help in **tutorials**,

- detailed explanation how to use a command
- examples

Usually you will find tutorials via the internet, sometimes there is a useful tutorial in the man page or info page.

- **Try some search strings** when you use your web browser's search engine, for example

  - *Looking for specified tools*

    - nano tutorial
    - sed tutorial
    - imagemagick tutorial
    - rsync tutorial
  - *Looking for tasks (and finding tutorials for various tools)*

    - linux text mode editor tutorial
    - linux batch mode picture editor tutorial

Look briefly at a few of the links that you find, and **start working with a tutorial that fits what you need**.

- `man rsync` is detailed enough for me to use as a tutorial, but you might want more details (and look for a tutorial via the internet).
- `info ddrescue` has a good built-in tutorial.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your constant contribution – I feel this question will grow a very useful source we can beginners point to. I'll add an index of contents to the question and link the answers to spare viewers the scrolling.

Comment: @dessert, This is a good initiative by you, and I'm glad to contribute :-)

Answer (score 3):

tldroid: An Android app which gives quick info about a Linux/unix/mac command

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.hidroh.tldroid

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse), have a function in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` like this

```bsh
cmd() { curl "http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/$(echo "$@" \
    | sed 's/ /-/g')/$(echo -n $@ | base64)/plaintext" ;}
```

Let's try `cmd mount cd`, I called my function `cmd`, you can call it whatever you want

[image]

The function above searches commandlinefu's website, it's a community driven website much like here, users have the ability to upvote commands and so on. Then it shows the top results as in the picture.

or there's a new way to do that by using [this](https://github.com/samirahmed/fu).

http://samirahmed.github.io/fu/

[Here's a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xeni7mHIVPE).

Let's do `fu cron`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figure out how to open a terminal window and issue the command `man man`. Type the space bar to advance to the next screen whenever it says "More" at the bottom. You are reading the manual page for the manual-reading program, `man`!

There is a very small chicken-and-egg problem for you to get through. The `man` command helps you read the manual about every command on the system. But the `man` output uses another command called `more`. You can also read `man more` to learn additional navigation commands for `more`.

And that is everything! I learned everything I know about unix by reading the man pages for hundreds of commands.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `man` uses `less` by default, not `more`.

Answer (score 0):

Many have mentioned `man` already. A little cool feature for `man` few are aware of is

```
man -t _$(manpage)_ > manpage.ps
```

which produces a PostScript file for the manual page. PostScript can be easily converted to PDF. This results in a much nicer formatting than the default command line terminal version of `man`.

For example:

```
man -t man > man.ps
pstopdf man.ps
```

I've just tested it on Ubuntu (and it should work on other Linuces) and Mac OS.