# How do I paste something from buffer directly to file using terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, paste

Recently, I'd copied some text from browser and I was too lazy too go and paste it in file by using file explorer.
I was wandering if I can paste it directly to the file by just using terminal and some commands.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can paste it onto the command line and use an echo command line to write it into a file like the following, `echo 'this text is pasted here' > file.txt` or if you want to *append* to the end of a file, `echo 'this text is pasted here' >> file.txt`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `cat`, with a *here document* e.g.

```
cat > somefile
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> then paste from the default buffer with a middle click or standard terminal emulator shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and terminate the input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Ex.

```
$ cat > somefile
foo
bar
baz
^D
```

Use `>>` in place of `>` if you want to append to `somefile` instead of overwrite it.

Comment: I had some problems with gnome-terminal in ubuntu, when I pasted a large number of lines, the pasting was truncated. I do not know if this has been fixed, but be warned.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `xclip` (`sudo apt install xclip`) for that:

```bsh
xclip -se c -o       # print the clipboard's content to stdout
xclip -se c -o >out  # print the clipboard's content to file named “out”
```

- `-se c` – use the `c`lipboard `se`lection, leave out or change to `-se p` to use the default buffer instead (the default buffer holds the last thing you *selected*, e.g. by double-clicking a word)
- `-o` – print to stdout
- `>out` – redirect stdout to file named `out` overwriting it, change to `>>out` to *append* to the file's content

See `man xclip` ([How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)) for more.