# getting synopsis inline

Tags: command-line, manpage, auto-completion

So this might be wierd question but is there anyway to get the synomposis of a command in the terminal?
what I mean by this is that if I write for example `find` I would like the terminal to write out the Synopsis part of the `man` page for `find`. I ofcourse don't want it to simply type everything in, but rather have a "grayed out" suggestion for what to write.

I think this would be extremely helpful for when you forget a specific command and don't want to simple go to the man page.

The `redis-cli` seems to do something like this...
The main part here is that I want it to be inline, i. e. like `redis-cli`:

[image: redis-cli image]

Comment: That is not really what I am after. In that question there is a function which searches for a command. I already know the command I want to use, I just need the synopsis for it while I am typing

Comment: I already contacted muru about it. Maybe one of the answers here can help you: https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051. I suppose what you really want is something like [cheat](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat) or [tldr](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr). Sadly I didn't manage to write answers covering those on the linked question yet, but the github pages are pretty good and self-explanatory.

Comment: @munHunger sorry, I read "when you forget a specific command" and felt the old dupe was more appropriate. I changed it to the one dessert suggested.

Comment: I still don't feel like my question has been answered on the other posts. Probably because I am bad at phrasing my question, but I want it to be inline... I added an image of how redis-cli does it, and I want something similar for my "normal" terminal

Comment: Inline? I don't think bash completion does inline anywhere (nor does zsh, AFAIK). With zsh, some completion functions show option descriptions below the prompt. But I haven't seen inline for bash or zsh. Try zsh and its tab completion, which offers suggestions on what the next argument can be (also on the next line)

Comment: Related: https://code.joejag.com/2014/why-zsh.html (see "killer tab completion" onwards)

Comment: @muru it looks as if zsh is as far as I get... but it seems like it will do :)