# less goto line requires me to type ':' twice

Tags: bash, less

Here is the behaviour im seeing:

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/MWuSbME041h8cmDqer

A short description is that when i type `man bash | less`, i need to type

```
::100
```

instead of

```
:100
```

in order to move to line 100.

I've tried googling it but couldnt really come up with sane search terms and it yielded nothihng.

Any ideas ?

My version of `less` is:

```
less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)
```

Comment: @guiverc `man` doesn't have its own pager, it uses the pager set in `$MANPAGER`, `$PAGER` or the one the alternatives system provides (which is `less` by default), whichever is set, in this exact order. As I explain in [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051) to use a specific pager one should use e.g. `man -P less bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Just to be clear: <kbd>G</kbd> means press this key and `g` means enter this character, so `G` = <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.</sub>

To navigate to a specific line in `less`, just enter a line number and press <kbd>G</kbd>. You don't enter the colon `:`, e.g. <kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to go to line 100.

Entering the same, but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>G</kbd> jumps *down* 100 lines instead. Here are the jumping commands from `less --help`:

```
Commands marked with * may be preceded by a number, N.

  g  <  ESC-<       *  Go to first line in file (or line N).
  G  >  ESC->       *  Go to last line in file (or line N).
  p  %              *  Go to beginning of file (or N percent into file).
```

Here's a list of possible combinations (for a standard US QWERTY keyboard where `<`=<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, `>`=<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and `%`=<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>):

- jump to the first line:

  - <kbd>G</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or
  - <kbd>P</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
- jump to line 8:

  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or
  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or
  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or
  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or
  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or
  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- jump 8 lines down:

  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- jump to 8% of the file:

  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or
  - <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
- jump to the last line:

  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>