# In crontab, what does "/usr/bin/php -f" do? Specifically, the -f

Tags: command-line, cron, php-cli

In crontab, what does `/usr/bin/php -f` do? Specifically, the `-f`

Not sure what that does, but I'm seeing it in a crontab I've came across.

Comment: From `man php`: "You can parse and execute files by using parameter `-f` followed by the name of the file to be executed."

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check `man php`:

```
   --file file
   -f file        Parse and execute file
```