# How can I find a file whose name fits a particular pattern using `find`?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, find

I'm learning Ubuntu in University and the task is find a file in the command line with the following instruction:

- file should start with letter `g`
- filename should have only 3 characters
- file extension must be `.d`

The search should be performed with the command `find`.

Comment: Did you read the `find` manpage? What is unclear there?

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Comment: Unclear how to find with only 3characters, starts with letter "g".

Comment: File or filename should start with g? If filename, does the character limit include the `.d` extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are allowed to use the `find` command, this is quite simple:

```
find / -type f -name "g??.d"
```

This will find all *files* (`-type f`) with a name that starts
with `g`, followed by two arbitrary characters `??`, followed
by `.d` (`-name "g??.d"`) in the root directory `/` and below.

When run as non-root user you will get many `permission denied`
errors because not all directories below `/` are accessible
by non-root. Also, it may take a while.

Change `/` to the path where you want to start the search from,
e.g. `/home/your_user` or simply `.` for the current directory.

Add `-ls` to get not only the file's names but also their attributes
(size, age, permissions):

```
find . -type f -name "g??.d" -ls
```