# How can I save my mouse sensitivity in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mouse

I am using this command here `xset m 1/2 8` but something I noticed is that I have to do it every time I log in. Is there a more permanent way of changing my mouse sensitivity?

Also what do the `1/2` and `8` pertain to for the mouse speed?

Comment: I also have a question of what the numbers pertain to as well.

Comment: This topic could be interesting for you: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/566421)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the numbers part: The first number is for acceleration and the second is for the threshold. From `man xset`:

```
By default the pointer (the on-screen representation  of  the  pointing
device)  will  go  `acceleration' times as fast when the device travels
more than `threshold' mickeys (i.e. would-be pixels) in 10 ms,  includ‐
ing a small transition range ...
```