# Where can I find documentation for readline?

Tags: bash

The `read` builtin command has  `-e` option

```
-e  Use Readline to handle input. This permits input editing in the same
    manner as the command line.
```

What's `Readline` in the specification:

```
$ man readline
No manual entry for readline
$ man Readline
No manual entry for Readline
```

There are no details of readline.

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051) – As `type read` reveals (and you already found out), `read` is a shell builtin. Those are documented in the shell's manual pages, so `man bash` is the correct source in your case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [`man bash`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#readline), which has an entire section on Readline:

```
READLINE
   This  is  the  library  that  handles  reading  input  when  using   an
   interactive  shell,  unless  the  --noediting  option is given at shell
   invocation.  Line editing is also used when using the -e option to  the
   read  builtin.
```

GNU Readline is a library that's developed alongside bash, but is used by a number of other programs to provide better interactive command-line usage (for example, Python's REPL loop). It can be configured using `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc`. See [the readline site](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) for more details.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think those are just for the API. The readline site's documentation is more comprehensive.

Comment: yep, the site might be a bit more comprehensive, but just in case someone stumbles around here looking for readline manpages, it actually a thing that exists.  Correction on my last comment, though, it's part of `readline-common` package, had to track it down via  `.list` files.

Answer (score 2):

To jump directly to the READLINE section of the bash man page, I define the following alias in my `$HOME/.bash_aliases` file.

```
alias man-readline="man -P 'less -p ^READLINE' bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `man 3 readline` for man page for Readline.

Comment: Note this requires `libreadline-devel` on some systems

Answer (score 1):

Use `info rluserman` for the complete manual, with interactive links.

Hit `H` and the bottom half of the screen will display a list of commands you can use to find what you need. Such as `[` and `]` to go through the nodes in `rluserman`. Or try to find something specific by starting a search, for example:

Suppose you were looking for the `vi-editing-mode`;

1. hit `/` to start a search
2. type your query, e.g. `vi`, and confirm by hitting `Enter`
3. use `{` and `}` to go back and forth through the occurrences in the manual.

(PS. `vi\W'`, would be better because this would rule out hits like 'pro*vi*ded')