# What is the use of -U in the pip install command?

Tags: command-line, python, pip

What is the use of `-U` in this `install` command?

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option upgrades all packages. From [`man pip`/INSTALL OPTIONS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pip.1.html#contenttoc5):

```
-U, --upgrade
          Upgrade all packages to  the  newest  available  version.   This
          process  is  recursive  regardless  of  whether  a dependency is
          already satisfied.
```

You might be interested in this Q&A: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)