# Options to use with configure for FFTW

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling

I am using the `./configure` command to install [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/download.html).

The `./configure --help` gives a list of options. How do I decide what options to use after `./configure`?

I know the explanation for each is given in `./configure --help` but is there any easy explanation for all options and when to use them?

Comment: @guiverc They mean the `./configure` file inside the tarball, which is a precursor step to running `make` and `sudo checkinstall`

Answer (score 4):

In the case of [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/download.html), the directory in the `tar.gz` file holds a file “INSTALL” which contains installation information, including options:

> You can give `configure' initial values for configuration
>   parameters by setting variables in the command line or in the
>   environment.  Here is an example:
>
> ```
>  ./configure CC=c99 CFLAGS=-g LIBS=-lposix
> ```

The document goes on and on about options and environment variables relevant for the `configure` script. If you need it, read the whole thing and you’ll be in the know. Note that `configure` is **not a command, but rather a script** which prepares the compiling. Because of that, every package usually has its own `configure` script that comes with it. As the examples in the “INSTALL” file of this specific package show, *this* `configure` script can take e.g. `gcc` and `g++` options. Read [their help files](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051) to learn about them.

However, if you just want to install the package and don’t know of options like that, the easiest way to do that is (requiring `auto-apt` and `checkinstall`<sup>1</sup>):

1. `cd` into the extracted directory named e.g. “fftw-3.3.7”
2. Run the package’s `configure` script and automatically install missing dependencies:

   ```
   auto-apt run ./configure
   ```

   The script reads environment variables to learn about the system it’s started on and automatically configures the makefile accordingly, it’ll suit your system without you specifying *any* options.
3. Run the `make` command to compile the source:

   ```
   make
   ```
4. Run `checkinstall` with root permissions to install the package:

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

<sup>1: `sudo apt install auto-apt checkinstall` to install both of them. `auto-apt` takes care of missing dependencies the package’s `configure` script reports, `checkinstall` creates a `.deb` package and installs it via the package manager so that you can easily remove the package later.</sup>