# What purpose does an .ok file serve in MRTG?

Tags: scripts, files, monitoring

I'm new in `mrtg` and I can't find what the `.ok` files do in a `mrtg` system. Could you help regarding this doubt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands)

Comment: @Melebius Oh, don’t let Zanna see this… ;) Seriously, I don’t think this other question is of any help here, the manpages etc. contain even less information on *this exact* matter than the online documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As even the [official documentation](https://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/index.en.html) doesn’t explain it I can only speculate, but there are some hints [here](https://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg.en.html):

```
--confcache-file filename
       Use an alternate confcache-file (the default is to use the
       configuration-file appended with ".ok")

--fhs
       Configure all mrtg paths to conform to the FHS specification.
       The following default values are assumed:

       confcachefile - /var/cache/mrtg/mrtg.ok
       pid-file      - /var/run/mrtg.pid
       lock-file     - /var/cache/mrtg/mrtg.lck
       log-file      - /var/log/mrtg.log
```

The `.ok` file seems to be a cache file holding the `mrtg` configuration, by default the `.ok` extension is just appended to a copy of the configuration file, but you may specify an own `.ok` file using the `--confcache-file` flag. If you use the `--fhs` option, the config cache file will be saved as `/var/cache/mrtg/mrtg.ok`.