# SimpleScreenRecorder covers my entire screen in a blue box

Tags: screencast, desktop-recording

As soon as I open SimpleScreenRecorder in Ubuntu 18.04 I get the standard input dialog. As soon as I pick the "record a fixed rectangle" radial button, my screen gets covered in this solid blue box that doesn't go away until I quit SimpleScreenRecorder.

I get it this a preview of the area that's going to be recorded. But it's on top of everything, is not transparent, and I can't see what I'm doing. It obscures SimpleScreenRecorder's own input dialog. I can hit `TAB` and guess where the cursor is to change settings. But this is maddening.

Turn this blue box off or make it transparent or something. How???

Comment: What version of ssr do you have? Is this the repo version or something else? You could post the content of `~/.ssr/settings.conf`. I don't have this issue with version 0.3.8-3.

Comment: Also consider installing `inxi` from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~unit193/+archive/ubuntu/inxi?field.series_filter=bionic) and then posting the output of `inxi -Fxxxz` for the relevant machine. More on `inxi` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072427/what-can-inxi-be-used-for).

Comment: Thanks, I just installed Kazam instead and it works. I might get around to troubleshooting this eventually.