# How do I list all devices and learn how to enable/disable them in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10, devices, peripherals

I'm looking for a way to see all the devices (e.g. touchpad etc.) and to enable/disable them.

Comment: Please see vanadium's answer. We like questions that deal with one specific issue.

Comment: I am not sure if it fits your needs, but you can have a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo

Comment: One convenient tool is *inxi*. You can install it using `sudo apt install inxi`. You can get a lot of information with it. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072427/what-can-inxi-be-used-for).

Comment: Hello @DKBose, which option should I consider to disable touchscreen in inxi?

Comment: Hi @FedonKadifeli, is it possible to disable devices by using hardinfo? I tried it, but it shows me only the list of the devices.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi that would be a good question to ask by posting a new question like "How do I disable my touchscreen in Ubuntu 19.10". *inxi* only provides information. It is not an interface for altering settings. By the way, I searched for "disable touchscreen in Ubuntu" and found this: https://www.tomordonez.com/disable-touchscreen-ubuntu.html. Does it help? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/198572/how-do-i-disable-the-touchscreen-drivers as well.

Comment: Perfect explanation @DKBose it's simple and fast to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux works different than Windows, and as such, a unified place to enable/disable devices is not available. This is also due to different mechanisms that drivers my use. Some drivers come directly with the kernel and can (or cannot) be disabled by blacklisting modules. Other drivers are working on Xorg and can be enabled/disabled by configuration files or installing/removing packages, etc.

If you have a specific need to disable a device, post here and specific answers for your device may be given.

Comment: Hi @vanadium thank you so much for the clarification about the Linux's world.

Comment: My pleasure - a simple answer, but sometimes that is OK to see things differently.

Answer (score 3):

type `xinput` and see the device id

```
$ xinput
```

To disable the device, type this line

```
$ xinput --disable xx xx adalah id device
```

To enable device, type this line

```
$ xinput --enable xx
```

See:https://gist.github.com/edomaru/5f6997cff92203824e43