# What does running "builtin" do?

Tags: bash

Simple question, really...

#### Builtin?

What happens when you run: `builtin`?

The return type from `echo $?` is `0`.

Which means that the command has most likely run successfully.

So, what does running `builtin` accomplish?

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is useful when you wish to reimplement a shell builtin
as a shell function, but need to execute the builtin within the function.

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin

$ function echo(){ builtin echo "'$1'"; }

$ echo hi
'hi'
```

---

```
help builtin
```

> builtin: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
>       Execute shell builtins.
>
> ```
> Execute SHELL-BUILTIN with arguments ARGs without performing command
> lookup.  This is useful when you wish to reimplement a shell builtin
> as a shell function, but need to execute the builtin within the function.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns the exit status of SHELL-BUILTIN, or false if SHELL-BUILTIN is
> not a shell builtin.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From `help -m builtin`:

```
NAME
    builtin - Execute shell builtins.

SYNOPSIS
    builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]

DESCRIPTION
    Execute shell builtins.

    Execute SHELL-BUILTIN with arguments ARGs without performing command
    lookup.  This is useful when you wish to reimplement a shell builtin
    as a shell function, but need to execute the builtin within the function.
```

Example usage:

```
cd (){
    builtin cd "$@"
    pwd
}
```

This `cd`'s, then prints the new working directory (like in IPython). If you forget the `builtin` part, it will keep calling itself in an infinite loop.