# How to find the manual of a command when `man <cmd>` doesn't work

Tags: command-line, manpage

When `man <cmd>` or `<cmd> --help` or `<cmd> -h` doesn't show you how to use the command, what should you do to get the information you need?

For example, the command `enable` has no manual page.

- Type `enable --invalid_option` will only show you the usage `enable: usage: enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [name ...]` without any explanation.
- Since the term **enable** is too generic, searching online for **ubuntu terminal command enable** will only give you lots of unwanted results.

So is there a best way to get the manual of a command, when `man <cmd>` doesn't work?

Comment: `enable`'s a builtin in zsh, so look at the zsh manual.

Comment: Here is another possible duplication: https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/566421