# Open a file with... in a Linux terminal

Tags: command-line, files, pdf

How can I open a file with another program than the default one with a command line in the terminal?

For example I want to open a PDF. To open it with the default PDF viewer I just write `xdg-open theFile.pdf`, but if I want to open it with "okular" for example, what command should I write?

Comment: `okular theFile.pdf`

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051) Usually `man PROGRAM_NAME`, e.g. `man okular`, provides syntax information like that.