# what does "-n" mean in a terminal command?

Tags: command-line, bash, anaconda

I found the following command online:

```
 conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
```

What does the "-n" mean in this command?

Comment: Have you tried `conda create --help` yet?

Comment: `-n` appears to be the short-form of `--name`. See for example [Creating an environment with commands](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands)

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html#Target%20Environment%20Specification):

> ```
> usage: conda create [-h] [--clone ENV] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [-c CHANNEL]
>                     [--use-local] [--override-channels]
>                     [--strict-channel-priority] [--no-channel-priority]
>                     [--no-deps | --only-deps] [--no-pin] [--copy] [-C] [-k]
>                     [--offline] [-d] [--json] [-q] [-v] [-y] [--download-only]
>                     [--show-channel-urls] [--file FILE]
>                     [--no-default-packages]
>                     [package_spec [package_spec ...]]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> -n, --name    Name of environment.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Every Linux command has a different set of arguments or flags - it's entirely up to the program. Some programs uses short flags like `-n`, some use long flags like `--thingy`, some use both, and some don't use "flags" at all like `dd if=foo of=bar`.

A common convention is for programs to list out their options when passed `--help` or `-h`, and many programs provide a Manual Page (manpage) which you can read using `man name_of_command`, although it looks like `conda` [may not have one](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/642).

Comment: does "-" or "--" have a "terminal-wide" syntactic status? or is it also just a convention?

Comment: It's just a convention. Many programs use it because there are libraries and tools for parsing the arguments (`getopt` in C, `argparse` in Python) and automatically generating help text or man pages.

Comment: For example, the program you're using `conda` uses Python's `argparse` to generate that `--help` text.