# Locking down a folder

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have very limited knowledge in all things Linux so if somebody could just tell me the commands I need to run to finish up this project I've been beating my head against.

I have a folder called `/data`, I have these 4 users `admin`, `nwadmin`, `hwadmin`, and `ro` and I need the user `ro` to have read-only access to that `/data` folder and all subfolders, while the other 3 users have full access.  What commands do I need to run to accomplish this, please?  Thanks in advance!

I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, I haven't tried anything yet as I'm scared to do so.  I know it probably uses `chown` and `chmod` but I don't understand those commands at all, no matter how many times I read how to do it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Is it a desktop or a server? What have you tried? What errors do you get? Please edit your question above and add all the details of your problem.

Comment: Sorry I have added more info, and yes Melibius I guess it would be fine to make it read only for all then a group for the 3 admins and owned by the admin group.  What commands would I run to do this in order please and thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set read+write permissions for a *group* of users and grant read-only access to everyone else. This can be done using the command line.

### Disclaimer & further reading

Before running any of the commands from the internet, you should understand what they do. The simplest way is to [read their manual pages](https://askubuntu.com/a/991947/250300).

### Procedure

1. Add (`+`) the **g**roup **w**rite and **r**ead permission for the folder **R**ecursively. Add the **r**ead permission and remove (`-`) the **w**rite permission for **o**thers.

   ```
   chmod -R g+rw,o+r-w /data
   ```

   Don’t change the permissions using number codes as especially the e**x**ecute permission may vary among files and folders and should be kept.
2. [Create a new group](https://superuser.com/q/624745/84807), e.g. `admins`, and add all the users who shall get read+write permissions to it.

   ```sh
   sudo addgroup admins
   for user in admin nwadmin hwadmin; do sudo adduser $user admins; done
   #              ↖    ↑    ↗
   #   list the users here
   ```
3. Set the folder as owned by the `admins` group (**R**ecursively).

   ```sh
   chgrp admins /data
   ```

### Additional notes

As you have claimed to “have very limited knowledge in all things Linux”, I’d like to bring your attention to the following concerns.

#### Using `sudo`

You can find a lot of `sudo chmod` commands on the internet. `sudo` should be only used for system-wide administrative tasks (like adding a new user group to the system above) but not to modify a user’s folder. Make sure to run the `chmod` and `chgrp` commands as the owner of the folder.

#### Paths

> I have a folder called /data

Paths beginning with a `/` are [absolute paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) on Linux. If your folder does not reside in the root (`/`) folder, make sure to put the right path in the above commands. The best way is to have the working directory set to the superfolder of `data` (e.g. if the folder is `/home/shared/data`, issue the command `cd /home/shared`) and then use `data` (without the leading `/`) as the path argument.

Comment: Thanks this was easy to understand and worked perfectly, appreciate you!

Comment: Done, thx again!