# Grant group traversal rights on a folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, lubuntu

I have a folder named `Dog` with these permissions:

```
dr--r-- 2 rich boys 4096
```

What is the shell command for it

Comment: "What is the shell command so that I can grant group traversal rights on this folder?" is missing the most important thing: for WHO? You already can, group can't and others can't.

Comment: @Rinzwind "What is the shell command so that I can grant ***group*** traversal rights on this folder?"

Comment: @Melebius there was a comment above mine that already stated this. From steeldriver iirc.

Comment: Has any of the answers solved your problem? Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657) it (✓) or clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments. You can also [upvote](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (▲) useful answers.

Answer (score 4):

The command is:

```
chmod g+x Dog
```

For opening the folder, you need the e**x**ecute permission. (When used on regular files, the same e**x**ecute permission allows running them.) This command simply sets it to the **g**roup without touching other permissions.

### Further reading

- [`man chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) (see also [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands/991947#991947))

Answer (score -1):

To give all rights (read, write and execute) to the owner and group; and no rights to others, run this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 750 ./Dog
```

Example:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir Dog
ll | grep Dog
    drwxr--r--  2 subroot subroot  4096 Mar 28 13:49 Dog/
sudo chmod -R 750 ./Dog
ll | grep Dog
    drwxrw----  2 subroot subroot  4096 Mar 28 13:49 Dog/
```

Comment: Technically correct but 777 is never really needed. 770, 775, 750, 755 are more safe options. 777 is for instance useful with the sticky bit option /tmp/ uses: files can be accessed if owned by that user or root

Comment: @Rinzwind Just realized that and corrected in time.

Comment: for group traversal rights 750 would be enough.

Comment: You should not set `770` recursively. Among others, it means setting the execute permission for all regular files (in addition to folders) which is likely not desired.