# Removing read access from a file

Tags: command-line

A file `Cat` within a folder `Dog` owner

```
-rw- 1 rich v 12 15:40 Cat
```

What is the shell command to remove others' read access from file `Dog`?

Comment: You *really* should be able to attempt this based on the answer you received in [Grant group traversal rights on a folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129365/grant-group-traversal-rights-on-a-folder) and a perusal of the relevant manual page (`man chmod`)

Comment: This is very unclear. Is it `cat` or `Cat`, and what is `Dog`? A file, a folder (which is a file as well in the end), …?

Answer (score 7):

You can change file permissions with the `chmod` command.

There are two basic ways of using `chmod` to change file permissions:

1. Symbolic Method:
   In the symbolic method to remove read and write permission for other users on a subdirectory named `Dog`, you should enter:

   ```
   chmod o-rw Dog
   ```
2. Absolute form:
   In the absolute method to do the same, you should enter:

   ```
   chmod 700 Dog
   ```

   for read, write, execute permissions only for the owner and not for the group and other users.
   In this method you can customize the access permissions more efficiently as per your requirements.

**Be careful when setting the permissions of directories, particularly your home directory; you don't want to lock yourself out by removing your own access. Also, you must have the execute permission on a directory to switch (cd) to it.**
[For further reading and additional information about file permissions.](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb)