# How to use grep to search through the --help output?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

When using `grep` or `egrep` to search through the output from a program with the `--help` parameter it prints the complete output instead of the lines that match.

Example:

```
ssh-keygen --help | grep "known_hosts"
unknown option -- -
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
       // etc
```

When searching for a parameter like `ssh-keygen --help | grep "-p"` grep recognizes this parameter for itself. Escaping the dash (i.e. `grep "\-p"`) does not help.

Example:

```
ssh-keygen --help | grep "-p"         
grep: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
unknown option -- -
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -l [-v] [-E fingerprint_hash] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
```

How to solve this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ssh-keygen` command doesn’t have a `--help` option, so it prints the “unknown option” error, silently thinks “RTFM” and outputs the help. It does this not on stdout but on *stderr*, which is not piped with `|` but only with `|&` (which is a `bash` shorthand for `2>&1 |`):

```
$ ssh-keygen --help |& grep "known_hosts"
       ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
       ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
```

A totally different issue is `grep` recognizing your search expression as an option because it starts with a hyphen. Fortunately `grep` is one of the many commands which recognize the “end of options” `--` option and takes everything behind it as an argument instead of an option:

```
$ ssh-keygen --help |& grep -- -p
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

`man grep` doesn’t even mention it, but here’s this option’s description from the `bash` manual:

> A `--` signals the end of options and disables  further  option  processing. Any arguments after the `--` are treated as filenames and arguments.

`grep` also provides a second way to deal with patterns beginning with “-”: The `-e` option takes a pattern as its argument, thus the following is equally possible:

```
$ ssh-keygen --help |& grep -e -p
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

#### Further reading

- [`man bash`/SHELL GRAMMAR/Pipelines](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20grammar)
- [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/246819)
- [`man grep`/OPTIONS/Matching Control](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html#options)

Comment: great post, but why do you think the grep manual should mention how the shell handles `--`? It doesn't mention other shell feature,too, like filename expansion, variable expansion, command substitution. There are a lot of things the shell does before te command is executed. I think the grep manual is not the right place for such details.

Comment: @miracle173 `bash` and some of its builtins understand `--`, but the shell does nothing with `grep -- -p` (what would that be?). It’s `grep` alone that understands this option and its special meaning, therefore its manual page should list it as an option.

Comment: you are right. I see now that it is restricted to some of the builtins. So it is actually a grep feature.

Comment: @miracle173 By implementing it `grep` followed [POSIX Utility Syntax Guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), so it’s not their idea, but still…

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is help on the ssh-keygen command try

```
man ssh-keygen | grep known_hosts
```

Or, you can do `man ssh-keygen` from a command line and then press <kbd>/</kbd> and type the search term, eg "kno", press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use <kbd>n</kbd> to continue to the next instance of the search term (`man man` for more info about using `man`). Note the `man` search only searches down, so use <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> to return to the start of the manual entry before starting a new search.

Answer (score 2):

You call `ssh-keygen` with a non-existent option.  That is an error, and error output appears on stderr.  It does not appear like `ssh-keygen` has a regular option for outputting its usage: if it had (like GNU programs have by default with `--help`), that "regular" output would appear on stdout and be accessible to less in the pipe you used.

You can kludge around this using `ssh-keygen --help 2>&1 | grep -e "-p"` : the `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout where the pipe can catch it, and `-e` as an option to grep means "the following is the regexp to use even if it looks like an option".

`man ssh-keygen` should work better for getting the usage and will pipe into `less` by default where you can search regular expressions with `/` , and reading in context is usually the better choice.