# What is "STRING" and "+%s" in this script using the date command?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have the following script (based on [this](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/run-while-loop-until-specific-time-shell-bash/)):

```
#!/bin/bash

runtime=$(zenity --title "Send notification repeatedly" --entry "Enter the period in minutes like this: nn minutes")

endtime=$(date -ud "$runtime" +%s)

while [[ $(date -u +%s) -le $endtime ]]
do
    notify-send "Hello"
    sleep 10s
done
```

`man date` has this:

> ```
>    -d, --date=STRING
>           display time described by STRING, not 'now'
> ```

but I couldn't find an explanation for "STRING".

All of the following work when entered in the zenity window:

- `1 minute`
- `1 minutes` and
- `1 min`

But `1 m` doesn't. Where is what is acceptable as "STRING" described? I couldn't find anything in `man date`.

The other thing is the purpose of `+%s`. What does it do?

Comment: I think you are looking for `info '(coreutils) date invocation'`

Comment: [parse-datetime](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/d7cf3b8d27f6b7ccbcdcdd9d18d7e12208795e3d/lib/parse-datetime.y#L1008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find it a bit below in `man date`:

> **DATE STRING**
>
> The  `--date=STRING`  is  a  mostly  free format human readable date string such as `"Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"` or `"2004-02-29 16:21:42"` or even `"next Thursday"`.
>   A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.
>   An empty string indicates the beginning of the day. The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but **is fully described in the info documentation**.

To get to know what exactly is allowed and what not, you can read the *info documentation*.

So, run `info date` and switch to "Date input formats".

---

Regarding `+%s` see the Synopsis:

```
date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
```

with FORMAT being a long number of possible sequences, so here just the one you need:

```
%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

The `+` is just part of the syntax.

---

Additionally, some good reading:  [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands)

Comment: See my answer for the meaning of `+`

Answer (score 1):

All is said inside the manpage :

> DATE STRING
>
> The `--date=STRING` is a mostly free format human readable date string
>   such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or
>   even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating
>   calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time,
>   relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning
>   of the day. The date string format is more complex than is easily
>   documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

Here is examples given :

> EXAMPLES
>
> Convert seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) to a date
>
> ```
> $ date --date='@2147483647'
> ```
>
> Show the time on the west coast of the US (use tzselect(1) to find TZ)
>
> ```
> $ TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date
> ```
>
> Show the local time for 9AM next Friday on the west coast of the US
>
> ```
> $ date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles" 09:00 next Fri'
> ```

You could also find that [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) on internet

Answer (score 1):

From `info '(coreutils) date invocation':`

> The program accepts the following options.  Also see *note Common
>   options::.
>
> ‘-d DATESTR’ ‘--date=DATESTR’
>        Display the date and time specified in DATESTR instead of the
>        current date and time.  DATESTR can be in almost any common format.
>        It can contain month names, time zones, ‘am’ and ‘pm’, ‘yesterday’,
>        etc.  For example, ‘--date="2004-02-27 14:19:13.489392193 +0530"’
>        specifies the instant of time that is 489,392,193 nanoseconds after
>        February 27, 2004 at 2:19:13 PM in a time zone that is 5 hours and
>        30 minutes east of UTC.
>        Note: input currently must be in locale independent format.  E.g.,
>        the LC_TIME=C below is needed to print back the correct date in
>        many locales:
>             date -d "$(LC_TIME=C date)"

The `+`:

> If given an argument that starts with a ‘+’, ‘date’ prints the current
>   date and time (or the date and time specified by the ‘--date’ option,
>   see below) in the format defined by that argument, which is similar to
>   that of the ‘strftime’ function.  Except for conversion specifiers,
>   which start with ‘%’, characters in the format string are printed
>   unchanged.  The conversion specifiers are described below.

The  `%s`:

> ‘date’ conversion specifiers related to times. ...
>
> ‘%s’
>        seconds since the epoch, i.e., since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  Leap
>        seconds are not counted unless leap second support is available.
>        *Note %s-examples::, for examples.  This is a GNU extension.