# Why do `ls -1 filename` just lists the filename?

Tags: command-line, ls

When I run `ls -1 filename`, it just lists the filename, instead of permissions with filename. However, according to online resources, the output should also have permissions details of the file. I used `stat` and that worked.

Comment: You're confusing `-1` (digit "one") with `-l` (letter "ell")

Comment: You need to be clear are the files on a windows 10 drive?

Comment: This is the behavior like stated in the documentation of `ls`. See `man ls` or more generally, check [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991946/how-can-i-get-help-on-terminal-commands)

Comment: Ahhhh yeah i was confusing it with 1 instead of l. ahahahaha funny. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-1` is a parameter to `ls` command that tells the command to list **only filenames**, one file per line (by default `ls` with no parameter lists as many filenames in a line as will fit in line width). So your command does exactly what it should.

If you want to list permissions and other data about files, you should use `-l` (for **l**ong), not `-1`.

Comment: It should be noted here that `ls -1` is really good for scripts, where you want to list all filenames only, do some filtering, and end up with a smaller list of names that can be read into an array etc.