# Where can I find the manual on for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I forgot the syntax and semantics for bash `for` loop and tried to find the manual in the system. I couldn't find it. It wasn't in `man bash` or `man builtins`. Where can I do a quick local reference on `bash` commands?

Comment: Does `help for` give you what you want? See for example [What is the help command?](https://askubuntu.com/a/992033/178692)

Comment: Have you tried Google? Go to www.google.com. Enter **bash for loop** in the search input box and see what comes up.

Comment: I don't want to use google. I wanted to find the answer using builtin manuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want more details than from the man pages. Here are also some examples

From `man bash`:

```
   for name [ in word ] ; do list ; done
          The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of
          items.  The variable name is set to each element of this list in
          turn,  and  list is executed each time.  If the in word is omit‐
          ted, the for command executes  list  once  for  each  positional
          parameter that is set (see PARAMETERS below).  The return status
          is the exit status of the last command that  executes.   If  the
          expansion of the items following in results in an empty list, no
          commands are executed, and the return status is 0.

   for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done
          First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to
          the  rules  described  below  under  ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  The
          arithmetic expression expr2 is then evaluated  repeatedly  until
          it  evaluates  to zero.  Each time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero
          value, list is executed and the arithmetic expression  expr3  is
          evaluated.   If  any  expression is omitted, it behaves as if it
          evaluates to 1.  The return value is the exit status of the last
          command in list that is executed, or false if any of the expres‐
          sions is invalid.
```

Examples:

```
for i in *.txt;do echo textfiles: $i;done

for (( i=1; i<=20 ; i++ )) ; do echo $i;done

for i in *.TXT;do mv $i ${i/\.TXT/}.txt; done  # "move *.TXT *.txt"
```

Comment: Doh! it was in `man bash` and I am  not sure why I missed it. Yeah, the examples weren't present.

Comment: And what I missed was, adding a do statement after `;` while using for loop.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran, I'm glad that I could help you find it :-)